# gnu make installed with OS language

Tags: mingw, gnu-make

I installed the latest GNU make to my windows machine.

The installer decided to setup the language as the OS language, which I did not get prompted for. I want it to be english. My OS is in swedish.

I remember I had similar problem with another GNU program (can't recall which), which was solved by adding the env var "lang" with value "c".

How can I switch the language of GNU make to english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of whether Windows has case sensitive environment variables, but I would expect GNU make to switch to completely switch to US English with `LANG=C`. If that does not help, try `LC_ALL=C`, or check whether there is a `locale` command in the mingw environment which could help show you the exact locale settings.

If you set these environment variables from within the mingw bash shell, make sure that the shell exports those environment variables to the processes it starts (such ask `make`). I.e. either set the values with `export FOO=bar` to begin with, or export them with a separate `export FOO` after having set them with `FOO=bar`.

(I am presuming mingw behaves like a standard GNU environment when it comes to locales.)

Comment: Your suggestions on env var did not work. Renaming the `locale` folder under `C:\program\gnuwin32\share\` did work. So removing the language data itself worked, thanks. But I also would like to know where the information to use a language is set? (and why GNU would setup in the OS language automatically, without prompting!)

Comment: You did export the variables, didn't you? Otherwise only the current shell will see the variable, but not the programs that shell starts.

Comment: No `locale` command makes sense in a "minimal" environment, but thanks for explicitly confirming that.

Comment: do you mean make sure that `make` knows about the env var? Yes, `LANG=C` has been on my machine for long. Plus I restart the shell every time I change an env var, then try `make` and read the output.

Answer (score 2):

My OS is Japanese, so the terminal was outputting gibberish. What worked for me was setting the `LANGUAGE` variable:

```
> make
make: *** ?^?[?Q?b?g?a?w’e?3?e?A?¨?c?，, makefile ?a?c?A?c?e?U?1?n.  ’†?~.
> set LANGUAGE=en_US
> make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Although [the documentation suggests otherwise](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html), I had no luck setting other environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

For me under Linux with German locale, passing this directly to make as follows works with bash:

```
$ make tfred
make: *** Keine Regel, um „tfred“ zu erstellen.  Schluss.
$ LANGUAGE=en_US make trffef
make: *** No rule to make target 'trffef'.  Stop.
```